# Count cell change individually

Tags: excel, counter, monitor

I have a little problem. I edited a code to count the cell changes for the selected cell what actually works great. This code goes into the sheets coding not as an individual macro to run.
How is possible to run the same code in parallel for different area counting separately from the other one watching different cells.
I tried with double IF what gave me an error and I tried the same code under different sub.

For the moment the code watching the C8 cells change and counts in D8.
I need to run another counter for C16 and to count in D18.
If I need to monitor multiple cells with separate counters how can I do it ?

```
    Dim xCount As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target = Range("C8") Then
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Range("D8").Value = xCount
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("C8"))
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Range("D8").Value = xCount
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Those "counters" are saved in the workbook until the code changes they count continuously and resets if the code changes.The workbook itself maintains the counter "position"  Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range, ranges, x As Long
    Dim deps As Range

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub '<<<<<<<< added this...

    On Error GoTo haveError

    ranges = Array("C8", "C16")

    For x = 0 To UBound(ranges)

        Set xCell = Range(ranges(x))

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xCell) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            xCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = xCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
        End If

        Set deps = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next         'suspend error trapping
        Set deps = Target.Dependents
        On Error GoTo haveError      'resume trapping

        If Not deps Is Nothing Then
            Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, xCell)
            If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                xCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = xCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next x

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't works. If I change something in C8 counts for D16 too.

Comment: I just linked a picture uploaded about the sheet. I have basically cells which are contain more "ingredients". If I change any of them I need a counter to count each changes by the different groups. That gonna be a batch coding system for warehouse.

https://i.imgur.com/6Fn4QVt.jpg

Comment: Your original post used a global variable to keep count - that only works in a single session and will always reset to zero if you re-open the workbook.  Is that really the behavior you wanted?

Comment: I don't want it to reset when I close and reopen. What I really need is my original code what I posted but to run 3 instance in the "same time" but to watch different cells changes. Probably needs an integer to watch the "last counter" 's position .. ? o.O

Comment: See my edits - I had left a line in from your original code, and removing the global/static counter simplifies the code a bit.

Comment: Just works perfectly !!! Exactly what I needed !!! Only a quick one. How can I manually reset a counter if it's needed ? Before it was possible with the reset button in code view

Comment: Delete the counter cell content

Comment: Thank You Williams. Would you able to help me in a little private project?

Comment: Sorry I don't do side projects (except for answering Q here...)